# Create dynamic NavBar menu with and without submenu and create <li> tag with different class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this issue - I would like to create a NavBar with submenus on some menu and without submenus for some items. I have a working piece that creates and loop through the menu items but what I am trying to achieve is to use different class name in li tag for different menus at the same time loop through the JSON object to know if that menu contains submenu are not using JS?

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul id="navbarId" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS:

```
    var data = {
    "Setup":
        [
            {  "type": "Submenu-1", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
            {  "type": "submenu-2", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
        ],
    "Report":
        [
            {  "type": "subreport-1", "link" : "https://www.google.com" },
            {  "type": "subreport-2", "link" : "https://www.google.com" }
        ],
    "logout":
        []

};

$(document).ready(function() {
    
    for (var item in data) { 
        var _menu = "";
        var _submenuData = data[item];
        if(_submenuData.length > 0) {
            var _submenu = "";
            
            for(var i = 0; i < _submenuData.length; i++) {
                _submenu += "<a class='dropdown-item' href='" + _submenuData[i]["link"] + "'>" + _submenuData[i]["type"] + "</a>";
        }
        
        _menu = "<li class='nav-item dropdown'>"
                + "<a class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href='' id='navbardrop' data-toggle='dropdown'> " + item + " </a>"
                + "<div id='drop' class='dropdown-menu'>"
                + _submenu
                + "</div>"
                + "</li>";
        }
        else {
            _menu = "<li class='nav-item'>"
                + "<a class='nav-link' href=''> " + item + " </a>"
                + "</li>";
        }
        
        $("#navbarId").append(_menu);
    }

});
```

What I am trying to achieve is li class="activemenu" li class="inactivemenu" something like this. each item in the JSON object should have a different class name. How to create multiple li divs for each item in the JSON object?

[image: Menus with a different class name to differentiate active and inactive menu]